# Is there any way to remove foley from dialogue?

Tags: audio, editing, filtering

I have a single wav file that has both dialogue and computer keys clicking at the same time, is there any way to do an FFT or noise filtering to just isolate the dialogue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Theoretically* this is achievable with [iZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx.html) software and a lot of patience.

The more keyboard clicks you have, the worse, but otherwise, this sound isn't the worst case scenario for this kind of software. You'll have to redraw every keystroke, though.